# change dropdown menu text to yellow in bootstrap3 collapsed mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I cannot change the grey text to yellow when a dropdown is clicked in a collapsed view. I have the example at http://www.bootply.com/zGzMrrmrWL

My code is all over the place because I have just been throwing things in to see if they work! I'm at that kind of desperation state! Can anybody show me what I haven't done? I simply want all the text to be yellow, whether it is in a dropdown or on the main menu

Comment: I'm not seeing any grey text.

Comment: in the drop down menus on the phone view. I'm building this menu just for the phone based view. When I click on the "about" link in the bootply on the phone view the second second drop down text is greay not yellow. I'm sorry for being unclear, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have..

`.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {color:#FFFF00; font-size: 18px;}`

in your CSS overrides to the specificity of `.dropdown-menu>li>a` isn't enough to override Bootstrap's CSS that is changing the color to grey.

http://bootply.com/GKs5h2XiZc

Comment: Thank you so much, this was not an easy one for me, and I really appreciate it - this worked perfectly, it changed the submenu text to the yellow color to match.